# How to make hudson build only most current build

Tags: triggers, hudson

### Question

How do I setup Hudson so that if one person triggers a build, Hudson will put it on the queue and wait lets say 2 minutes, and during those 2 minutes if another build is triggered it will replace the older build on the queue with the new build?

This way if there are 2 builds in those 2 minutes, Hudson will only perform the last build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under *Manage Hudson*, set the **Quiet Period**.

> If set, a newly scheduled build waits for this many seconds before actually being built. This is useful for:
>
> - Collapsing multiple CVS change notification e-mails into one (some CVS changelog e-mail generation scripts generate multiple e-mails in quick succession when a commit spans across directories).
> - If your coding style is such that you commit one logical change in a few cvs/svn operations, then setting a longer quiet period would prevent Hudson from building it prematurely and reporting a failure.
> - Throttling builds. If your Hudson installation is too busy with too many builds, setting a longer quiet period can reduce the number of builds.
>
> If not explicitly set at project-level, the system-wide default value is used.

Comment: how do i set configure it to do what I stated earlier?

Comment: @MikeU, if you set the Quiet Period to 120 seconds, after the first commit, Hudson will wait for 2 minutes before starting the build. If another commit happens in that 2 minutes, Hudson will delay starting the build for another 2 minutes after the second commit. I think this accomplishes your goal of only building once if there are multiple commits (triggers) in close succession.

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I wanted.